# `@ConditionalOnProperty` used with multiple `@PropertySource`

Tags: spring-boot

I have some beans with `@ConditionalOnProperty`, where the property is taken from some `@PropertySource`. But I have multiple `@PropertySources`. Only in one of them, given property for condition will be defined. But for my surprise, the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation consults *every* property source. And since property isn't in every property source, `PropertyResolver` will flag bean as non-mathing.

What I'd like to have, is interface, with actual implementation and no-op implementation, and control which implementation will be used. I don't want to control it using profile, but profile is based on conditionals so there should be a way. So what is happening for me is, that I'm regardless of setting left out with no implementation. Sure, I can add `matchIfMissing`, and then I will be left out with both, regardless of setting.

Annotation is:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "feature.enabled", havingValue = "true")
```

and in property file is

```
feature.enabled=true
```

What is wrong here? But it really cannot be, that if I'm using @Conditional... I have to use just one property source, right?

UPDATE:
having following beans definitions, I have behavior as described: no bean is registered, because `feature.enabled` is not defined in `application.properties`. Adding `matchIfMissing=true` does not help, because bean with this parameter will be added always, since it's (always) not present in `application.properties`. Adding @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not help me also. I set `feature.enabled` to true in `another.properties`, but that FeatureImpl got vetoed, because there is property source, where feature.enabled isn't true. And surprisingly FeatureNoOp, at that time annotated with @ConditionalOnMissingBean, wasn't registered either. No idea why.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "feature.enabled", havingValue = "false")
public class FeatureNoOp implements Feature {
```

vs

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "feature.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class FeatureImpl implements Feature {
```

And configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Config {

    //...


    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:another.properties")
    @Profile("war-deployment")
    public static class WarDeploymentConfig {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: It checks the `Environment` which in turn checks all property sources in the order they are defined in. Which is how it should work. You should have a default implementation which matches if the value is something different (or when not defined hence you will need to add the `matchIfMissing` to that clause.).

Comment: I lead with setting, that *NoOp operation will be default implementation, and that one will have matchIfMissing. But since the other one won't be ever picked, this defaulted to NoOp is always used regardless of feature.enabled=? configuration. I also tried to play with @ConditionalOnMissingBean, assuming, that that one would be picked if no other beans exists. But that does not work either. I set enabled to true, and actualImpl is not picked. No idea why. And also NoOp is not picked, crashing on missing interface implementation.

Comment: I guess all this happens before property source with given configuration is consulted. I tried to put some `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`, but did not help either. Can you shed some light, how property sources are used? I have configuration class, annotated with property sources. Then another Configuration dependant on `@Profile` with another propertySource. But it seems, that the `@Profile` dependant one is processed too late.

Comment: Please add both bean declarations to your question as that should simply work. One issue though is that you are using `@PropertySource` instead of adding it to the `application.properties`, evaluation might be done early on in the Spring Boot lifecycle leading to not checking the `@PropertySource` definitions yet. Instead it probably is better to load those files by specifying the `spring.additional.locations` variable instead. (See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The true cause was, as M.Deinum correctly suggested (thanks!), in @PropertySource annotations.

I had @PropertySource for application.properties, plus I have some configuration classes like one below, just to bring another property source based on active profile:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:profile-related-properties.properties")
@Profile("some-profile")
public static class SomeProfileConfig {}
```

even if this provide some explicit saying what's being used, it apparently spells some issues. I changed the code, so that I do not 'repeatedly' declare usage on application.properties and renamed files/profiles so that another automatically discovered properties pattern can be used: application-{profile_name}.properties. After this change, everything works as expected.