# How to load PropertySources sooner in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have currently a problem in my DEV environment. I have for Spring Security two configurations, one for the Admin part of my application and the other for the rest of the user. For the admin part, I create one or another depending on beans decorated with a Conditional annotation. This conditionals rely on some property that is loaded from a class that is annotated with `@PropertySource` and this is important, this property I cannot set it neither in `application.properties` nor `application-<environment>.properties`. The problem comes that when these conditionals are evaluated because are spring security classes, the properties that are expected to perform such evaluation are not available, they come in a later stage, when Spring boot do some refresh context. My question is how I can do it do this class annotated with `@Configuration` `@PropertySources` to be loaded much sooner, right after the Profile is processed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot. I also wonder why wouldn't it be possible to place them in `application.properties` or other configs that are automatically loaded by Spring Boot.

Comment: In general you can check conditional on properties and in general you can have custom properties file loaded via PropertySource, so it shall work I suppose. Of course you have to have the properties loaded beforehand by utilising a custom config class. But then again it should work. Have a look in here, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54108121/conditionalonproperty-used-with-multiple-propertysource

Comment: @M.Deinum the problem is that in the properties files some passwords are stored, we develop and another company does the deployments, therefore we need several configs per environment.

Comment: @phaen as I mentioned, I would have the properties in a file of the classpath, could not be a problem, but in this case is not possible, and because is a springSecurity configuration it is loaded quite soon.

Comment: Just let Spring Boot load those files, specify where to find them and Spring Boot will load them (as explained in the reference guide). Or just add an external application.properties next to the jar (instead of a file loaded by you) and it will be loaded automatically.

Comment: The files are loaded correctly, what I really would like to change is the stage where these are loaded. I think i will need to add the external application.properties, it is what is done in the other environments and it is working, but I was curious how to control the phase of the stage where this configuration is processed.